# Crossfading between images as background-image in Semantic-UI

Tags: jquery, css, semantic-ui

What I want is to crossfade between two images (in jsfiddle to simplify example I've used colors). The images have to be background of div.

As you can see in the fiddle the behaviour is strange - after all div goes back to its previous css atribute.

I use semantic-ui.

http://jsfiddle.net/ksf0jdmy/

jQuery code:

`$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#maindiv').transition('fade').css('background-color','red').transition('fade');
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks to be more of an issue with the `fade()`function. It doesn't seem to preserve any changes made to the #maindiv element after the first call to `fade()`.

You can use CSS transitions to do what you're trying to do (just be aware of the browser support with CSS transitions. If you need more browser support, [jQuery animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) might be more useful to you).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7vm6rhs3/